# Почему Java позволяет запускать код конструктора в другом конструкторе

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

private Test(int n){
    String strang = null;
    System.out.println("Test " + n + " " + strang);
}
protected Test(){
    System.out.println("Protected");
    Test n = new Test(1);
}


public static void main(String[]arg){

    Test test = new Test();
}
}
```

Comment: @Lexis А в чем проблема? что вас смущает?

Comment: убираю private. все как работало так и работает.

Comment: Artem Konovalov в гибкости. почему java не бьет меня по рукам за такое?

Comment: Так вы запускаете это в том же классе. А там можно вытворять с собой все что угодно. Хоть заставить пироги печь

Comment: @Lexis потому что в конструкторе вы создаете новый инстанс того же класса, а тут уже вопрос в целеообразности, нужен он вам или нет, java решить за вас не может

Answer (score 2):

у вас `public static void main(String[]arg){` находится в пределах видимости методов и конструктора с любым модификатором. поэтому код выполняется.

Если вынести Main в другой класс, тоже заработает, потому что модификатор `protected` позволяет вызывать метод из вне, но не виден при наследовании.

Comment: модификаторы доступа для конструктора работают по общим принципам также как и для методов так и для класса?

Comment: @Lexis да, ты прав